# What is the difference between aria-errormessage and aria-alert?

Tags: html, attributes, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I am new to accessibility types. There is confusion as to when to use `aria-errormessage` and when to use `aria-alert`.

I need to display one of these in an `aria-live` region. Which should I use and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an either/or situation.  [`aria-errormessage`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-errormessage) is new in ARIA 1.1.  The value of `aria-errormessage` is the ID of another object (similar to `aria-labelledby` and `aria-describedby`) that contains the text of your error.  It's a way to "connect" your object with the error it's associated with.  That's all there is to it.

`aria-live` is used when you want changes announced and can certainly be used in error conditions but is also used whenever you change the text on your page and want the text change announced, such as if you have a timer or a stock ticker or a status indicator (such as if a wifi connection is lost).

`role="alert"` is a "shortcut" for setting `aria-live="assertive"` and `"aria-atomic="true"`.  It will cause the word "alert" to be announced and then your text change is read.  Error messages don't necessarily have to be alerts.  If I have an input field requiring a certain format and I make a mistake, an error should be announced but it's not so critical that it has to be an alert.  It could be a simple `aria-live="polite"`.

Keep in mind that if you use alert (meaning aria-live of assertive) and you have several alert roles, that some alerts can clear the queue of other alerts and you'd only hear one of them.

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-live

> User agents or assistive technologies **MAY** choose to clear queued
>   changes when an assertive change occurs. (e.g., changes in an
>   assertive region may remove all currently queued changes)

Comment: I need some more help in accessibility context. Some content is not read out in screenreader and iframes are not read. Can you pls give me your mail id so that i can mail you directly.

Comment: an `<iframe>` itself can have a label using the `title` attribute.  the contents of the iframe will be read like any other object as you tab through the interface.  if you have other accessibility questions, it might be good to search stackoverflow first using the `[accessibility]` tag (like you tagged your question) and if not found, post your question.  others might be interested in the question and answer too.  otherwise, i'm a senior accessibility specialist that contracts out and am available for hire. add your contact info to your stackoverflow profile and i can contact you.